# hbase how to scan with the key contains '\1'

Tags: java, hbase

my rowkey is like `u\x01-1\x012014-10-13 11:19:19\x01984624111`
the `\x01` means `\1`.

I tried `\x01` and `\1` ,but it not works.how can i scan start with "`u\x01-1`"?
is it the same problem in java program?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
String str="u\\x01-1\\x012014-10-13 11:19:19\\x01984624111";
        String []data=str.split("\\\\x01");
        for (String string : data) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
```

output :

```
u
-1
2014-10-13 11:19:19
984624111
```

Comment: it works in java but it do not work in hbase ,thanks